# Paragraph tags in different browsers with SDL Tridion?

Tags: cms

In the SDL Tridion 2011 content management system, when editing a component in a rich text field (RTF) I noticed pressing enter results in different HTML tags in the source.

I think it's based on browser since I get `<div>` with Chrome. How do I make sure I get `<p>` tags in all browsers?

**Update:**
SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 has the following in the default XSLT schema rich text filter, which appears to fix the scenario of pressing enter when editing regular Body Text or paragraphs. I still have the issue when pressing enter after a heading, which comes out as a `div` in Chrome.

```
<stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" cdata-section-elements="script"></output>
    <template match="/ | node() | @*">
        <copy>
            <apply-templates select="node() | @*"></apply-templates>
        </copy>
    </template>
    <template match="*[      (self::br or self::p or self::div)     and      normalize-space(translate(., &apos; &apos;, &apos;&apos;)) = &apos;&apos;     and      not(@*)     and      not(processing-instruction())     and      not(comment())     and      not(*[not(self::br) or @* or * or node()])     and      not(following::node()[not(         (self::text() or self::br or self::p or self::div)        and         normalize-space(translate(., &apos; &apos;, &apos;&apos;)) = &apos;&apos;        and         not(@*)        and         not(processing-instruction())        and         not(comment())        and         not(*[not(self::br) or @* or * or node()])       )])     ]">
        <!-- ignore all paragraphs and line-breaks at the end that have nothing but (non-breaking) spaces and line breaks -->
    </template>
    <template match="br[parent::div and not(preceding-sibling::node()) and not(following-sibling::node())]">
        <!-- Chrome generates <div><br/></div>. Renders differently in different browsers. Replace it with a non-breaking space -->
        <text> </text>
    </template>
</stylesheet>
```

Updated question then is:

**How do I make sure I get `<p>` tags in all browsers, even when pressing enter after a heading?**

Answer (score 6):

The problem is not new, and is a general problem with using contenteditable.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735672/how-to-change-behavior-of-contenteditable-blocks-after-on-enter-pressed-in-vario

Telerik as brought out a solution, where you can specify which behavior you want, something I suggest SDL also do.
http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-using-newlinebr-property.html

But it appear it just did not get attention yet.  The bigger question is, when does SDL start make use of HTML 5...

Comment: Thanks, @Hendrik. I see SP1 fixed some of this with an XSLT filter change, but not returns after headings.

Answer (score 5):

We have exactly the same issue - this is based on specific browser behavior. I have found Fire Fox, IE and Chrome to all give different results. If memory serves well:

- IE gives `<p>` tags
- Fire Fox gives a double `<br/>`
- Chrome uses a `<div/>` tag

I have a ticket filed with Customer Support about this, but as of now, I still don't have a solution. So we paste content into the field at the moment rather than actually editing in it otherwise it messes up our XHTML standards and our CSS does not work correctly.

Comment: I don't remember the version I was on (definitely before SP1, but either GA or Hotfix Rollup) and I had the same behavior.

I have the following version on my test machine and get `<p>` tags with Chrome in RTF by pressing enter now.
`Content Manager Explorer - Build 6.1.0.55920 
Content Manager - Build 6.1.0.996 
Update Version - SP1`

However, after changing text to a heading level, pressing return gives me a new "Generic container (div)" or `<div>`. I'd expect a paragraph, similar to how Word does `<p>` by default.